# I was trying to swap first 2 nodes in linked list, but been facing a problem

Tags: c, function, pointers, dynamic, linked-list

here a,b,c are pointers to first 3 consecutive nodes of a singly ll. The query I have is that why does changing ptr->next=a change the address stored in b->next

```
void sort(node **head){
int first=1;
node *ptr=*head;
if(first==1){
    first=0;
    if((ptr->data)>(ptr->next->data)){
        node *a=ptr;
        node *b=ptr->next;
        node *c=ptr->next->next;
        printf("\n%p\n",b->next);
        ptr=ptr->next;
        printf("\n%p,%p\n",b->next,c);
        ptr->next=a;
        printf("\n%p\n",a );
        printf("\n%p,%p\n",b->next,c);
        a->next=c;

        display(ptr);   

    }
```

the output I get is

```
0x55e7eb4b72e0

0x55e7eb4b72e0,0x55e7eb4b72e0

0x55e7eb4b72a0

0x55e7eb4b72a0,0x55e7eb4b72e0
5
6
4
2
```

Comment: After the line `ptr=ptr->next;`, try `printf("%p,%p\n", ptr, b);`

Comment: @user3386109 tried it, the output is as expected, both have same address

Comment: Ok, so what's the mystery? `ptr` and `b` point to the same `node`. If you change the node's `next` pointer using `ptr->next = a`, why wouldn't that change `b->next`?

Comment: @user3386109 oh, silly of me to miss that even after u pointing out...thanks

Comment: @ RasenRhino No problem, silly mistakes are how we learn :)